# Update columns in DB2 using randomly chosen static values provided at runtime

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, jdbctemplate

I would like to update rows with values chosen randomly from a set of possible values.

Ideally I would be able to provide this values at runtime, using `JdbcTemplate` from Java application.

Example: 
In a table, column "name" can contain any name. The goal is to run through the table and change all names to equal to either "Bob" or "Alice".

I know that this can be done by creating a sql function. I tested it and it was fine but I wonder if it is possible to just use simple query?

This will not work, seems that the value is computed once, and applied to all rows:

```
UPDATE test.table
SET first_name = 
    (SELECT a.name 
     FROM 
         (SELECT a.name, RAND() idx 
          FROM (VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob')) AS a(name) ORDER BY idx FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) as a)
;
```

I tried using `MERGE INTO`, but it won't even run (possible_names is not found in `SET` query). I am yet to figure out why:

```
MERGE INTO test.table
    USING
        (SELECT
            names.fname 
        FROM 
            (VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob'), ('Rob')) AS names(fname)) AS possible_names
    ON ( test.table.first_name IS NOT NULL )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET
        -- select random name
        first_name = (SELECT fname FROM possible_names ORDER BY idx FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
;
```

EDIT: If possible, I would like to only focus on fields being updated and not depend on knowing primary keys and such.

Answer (score 2):

Db2 seems to be optimizing away the subselect that returns your supposedly random name, materializing it only once, hence all rows in the target table receive the same value.

To force subselect execution for each row you need to somehow correlate it to the table being updated, for example:

```
UPDATE test.table
SET first_name = 
    (SELECT a.name 
     FROM (VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob')) AS a(name) 
     ORDER BY RAND(ASCII(SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1))) 
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
```

or may be even

```
UPDATE test.table
SET first_name = 
    (SELECT a.name 
     FROM (VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob')) AS a(name) 
     ORDER BY first_name, RAND() 
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
```

Now that the result of subselect seems to depend on the value of the corresponding row in the target table, there's no choice but to execute it for each row.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it should work, but after some testing it seems like the subselect is still optimized away.

Comment: I tested it and it works as described on Db2 for LUW 10.5

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a primary key, this would work. I've assumed the PK is column `id`.

```
UPDATE test.table t
SET first_name = 
( SELECT name from
    ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY R) AS RN FROM 
        ( SELECT *, RAND() R
          FROM test.table, TABLE(VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob')) AS d(name)  
         )
     )
 AS u
WHERE t.id = u.id and rn = 1
)
;
```

There might be a nicer/more efficient solution, but I'll leave that to others.

FYI I used the following DDL and data to test the above.

```
create table test.table(id int not null primary key, first_name varchar(32));
insert into test.table values (1,'Flo'),(2,'Fred'),(3,'Sue'),(4,'John'),(5,'Jim');
```

Comment: I had to modify this a bit, but yeah, it could work if primary keys are known. For my problem I would like to only focus on fields that are being  updated.

Comment: The code in the other answer should work. Db2 won't optimize away the correlation if it will change the semantics of the query. You need to ensure you have a non-redundant reference to the updated table in the correlated sub-select. This is a slightly more minimal version `UPDATE test.table t SET first_name = (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Alice'), ('Bob')) ORDER BY RAND(), t.first_name LIMIT 1)`